# Workarounds for a LoadLibrary failure in R

Tags: r, cran, loadlibrary

My organisation has updated security and I am now having trouble loading Tidyverse (I so far have not had problems with any other packages, but a colleague was getting the same error with a few others)

The error message that I keep getting is:

> LoadLibrary failure: Your organization used Device Guard to block this app. Contact your support person for more info.

Unsurprisingly, I have got in touch with IT but that will likely take a few days and I kind of need to get working with Tidyverse right now.

Can anyone please suggest any other methods to load a library that I could try or some sort of workaround to help me out until I can whitelist R packages?

Thanks!

Comment: Please clarify: This is an error message given within R? Because it doesn't really look like it is. A quick google search seems to indicate that this would be an error message outside R. (And really, nobody needs the tidyverse package. That package is a "meta-package", which basically means it combines a huge number of packages into one package. You could, I'd even say should, just use the individual packages.) Ultimately, you need to pressure your IT support.

Comment: Hi @Roland the error is given within RStudio when I run the code library ("tidyverse").
Point taken, I will try to run the individual packages as required, but given my colleague's experience I am somewhat expecting there to be problems with other packages too!
Out of interest why do you say that one should use the individual packages rather than load them through tidyverse? 
Thanks for your comment :)

Comment: Maybe just try in Rgui.

Comment: The more packages you have loaded the more potential there is to conflict with other packages you might want to load.

Comment: @Roland very annoyingly the same error message appears in rgui